# adding member to dynamic distribution group in outlook

Tags: powershell, dynamic, outlook, distribution

I have been trying to lookup how to add a new member to a dynamic distribution group, I came upon this, but it doesn't work...I think there is some other function because this seems to be for regular groups:

```
Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity "g1white students" -Member admin@live.cndl.edu
```

the dynamic group has been created using:

```
New-DynamicDistributionGroup -Name "g1white students" -alias g1whiteStudents -RecipientFilter {(RecipientType -eq 'UserMailbox') -and (CustomAttribute2 -like 'G1') -and (CustomAttribute3 -like 'White')}
```

how can I add the admin to be part of the people in the dynamic group,

what I ultimately want is that the admin receives a copy of the emails sent to the group
I have already added permission for admin to be able to send emails to the group using:

```
 Set-DynamicDistributionGroup  "g1white students" -AcceptMessagesOnlyFromSendersOrMembers "g1white students","admins"
```

(where admins is a ddg that contains the list of people allowed to send emails to all groups)

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic Distribution Group members are auto calculated based on the filter and conditions you set. I imagine that the admin needs to set the attribute that you know is being filtered for the distribution group.

Comment: yes I know, that's how I did them, but I need to add 1 other DDG or user to the already created ones but it did not seem to work with the above command